# Does Intel Cache Allocation Technology allow hits from CPUs in one group on cache lines in another group?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, intel, cpu-cache

In [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), if a cacheline needs to be loaded into a cache, the CPU will issue a `PrRd`. Depending whether the cacheline is already in another cache, a `BusRd` is issued. And other caches will then see the `BusRd` and check if they have a valid copy. If yes, this cache will send value.

Now intel CAT (Cache Allocation Technology) provides a way to isolate LLC cache usage to different CPUs. For example, CPU1 uses the first 8 ways and CPU2 uses the next 8 ways. My question is: if now CPU1 needs to load a cacheline which is in CPU2's cache, will CPU2 send that copy instead of loading from main memory?

Comment: The MESI wiki article describes it in terms of an old-school shared-bus design with 1 level of caching.  Real CPUs use a "directory" to filter snoops instead of having all traffic seen by all CPUs.  Intel's LLC is shared, so is basically separate from MESI between private caches.  Even without that, I don't see what your 1st paragraph has to do with your actual question, about whether CAT allows hits in the other partition of cache, or whether the same data could get cached twice or what.

Comment: @PeterCordes I may have not described the question is a proper way since I am new to this field. My intention in paragraph 1 is that there eists some mechanism (MESI) to allow cachelines be shared (through messaging, meaning cached contents are sent, instead of loading from next level cache or memory), even if CPU's l1 cache is separated. Now comes to l3 caches, normally it is shared (physically). But CAT can make them not shared. My question is when CAT is used, will the cacheline in LLC still be shared using MESI protocals (or other protocals)? Or memory load is needed in this case.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks very much for your input. I can modify the question if the above reply is more sound.

Comment: Terminology apart, this is indeed a very valid question to me. CAT is most likely implemented by having the Capacity Bit Masks partition the ways of every set. This way the indexing in the cache stays the same. This also means that two processes in two different COS will only share a line with probability `popcnt(CBM1 & CBM2)/nway`. There is a probability because not only the two processes must have overlapping CBMs but the line must go in the shared ways out of all the possible ones. So if process A can access ways 1,2,3 and process B 3,4 then if A reads X it must go in way 3 (out of 1,2,3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. CAT is not a form of NUMA, the address space is still shared.
It's just a micro-architectural feature that helps you control the cache occupancy so threads will have less interferences with each other (or have access to more caching opportunities, depending on how you allocate the masks).

If you don't return data from the other thread partition you will lose your coherence (what if the line is modified? you can't return stale data from the memory in that case).
Think of it like this - each thread can lookup from the entire cache, but allocate only to his partition (this could easily be implemented by hacking the LRU and victim selection).
This way you get full control over private lines, and only shared lines will be placed in the partition of whichever thread accessed them first. Close enough to get what QoS was needed for.

One open implementation question could be this - what happens what you allocate a line in one partition, but continue using it only by the other thread. Will it *eventually* get migrated to the other partition? My guess is no, simply because it's too much of a hassle to detect and organize.

Comment: If it ever gets evicted, it'll get allocated again by the next use.  Which will be by the thread that's still using it.   I wonder if hits from outside this CAT group refresh its LRU status or not?  If not, this CAT group would tend to evict it when allocating other lines in that set.  So things would tend to balance out over time, with CAT groups not being able to reliably steal space from other groups long-term unless both groups consistently access a line to keep it hot.  (I don't know if it works this way or not, but it seems plausible.  And pseudo-LRU leads to random evictions anyway.)

Comment: @PeterCordes,  Sure, if the line is dropped it can be re-allocated in a new partition. I assume LRU is managed properly per group, otherwise you would get horrible slowdowns when using this feature (I would also expect a zero-change when allocating all ways to a single partition). I don't think they use PLRU for last level caches, this would pretty much force the partitions to be power-of-2 which we know is not the case. Probably some age-based LRU instead which is easier to implement.

Comment: @Leeor Thanks very much for your answer. I upvoted it. I still have some question here, could you please help? Say I have thread A running in CPU1 and thread B in CPU2. CPU1 and CPU2 has distinct L3 cache due to CAT. If they both need to write to a the same 64bytes of memory, they each will have a copy of this in their own cache. L3 is inclusive, won't this lead to two copy of the same cacheline in L3? If there are two copies, how is the coherence maintained?

Comment: @doraemon, first of all, they will not have distinct modified copies of the same line in their local caches due to MESI coherence. You can only have a clean line shared. A modified line has to be owned exclusively. Second, the L3 doesn't allow replications like you said. If it is inclusive (most processors today are not, but let's say you found one that is...), I expect the first core who brings the line to allocate it in his subset, and the second core will be allowed to hit and modify it (again, governed by correct MESI behavior).

Comment: Like I said, the partitioning can be enforced during the replacement policy only. If there's no line allocation, there's no change. A lookup and WB of an existing line does not trigger replacemnt.